# How to use Next.js SPA with firebase auth state persistence

Tags: firebase, session, firebase-authentication, next.js

When trying to set firebase auth state persistence with the following code:

```
this.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
```

it says Next.js does not allow `setPersistence` to take params except `none`, because it will mess up with SSR.

However, I am trying to mainly use Next.js with SPA.
It there a way to configure Next.js to allow other `setPersistence` params?